# Create object on startup and share across requests

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I would like to use my Django application as a relay for a session-based online service and share this session among all users. For this, I've configured a [python-requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) Session object.

I would like to initialise this Session when Django starts up and keep it alive forever. My idea is to have all requests to my Django application share the session object by allowing the view for the particular request access the session object.

In **Flask** setting this up (for experimental purposes) is fairly easy:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session
from requests import Session
app = Flask(__name__)

session = Session()
session.post()        # Setup Session by logging in

@app.route("/")
def use_session():
    reply = session.get()   # Get resource from web service
    return jsonify(reply)
```

Here `session` would be created when starting and can be accessed by `use_session()`.

I struggle to set up the same in Django though. Where would be the preferred place to create the session?

Comment: What have you tried Django-wise? You can put the same logic in the Django's views.py (it's not a very good way to persist the session though)

Comment: What's the "session-based online service"? You'll need to include logic to determine if it has logged you out, so you can then reauthenticate, and make sure no other requests are made while the authentication process takes place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of your Flask code in Django would be to put the same logic in a `views.py` file:

```py
# yourapp/views.py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from requests import Session

session = Session()
session.post('https://httpbin.org/post')  # Setup Session by logging in


def use_session(request):
    reply = session.get('https://example.com')  # Get resource from web service
    return HttpResponse(reply.content, status=reply.status_code)
```

```py
# yourproject/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from yourapp.views import use_session


urlpatterns = [
    path('', use_session)
]
```

The object will get created as you start the server.

One problem with this approach is that in a real-world deployment you normally run multiple copies of your app (doesn't matter if it's Flask or Django or any other framework) to avoid thread blocking, utilize multiple CPU cores on the same server or have multiple servers, each copy will end up with its own session, which might work fine, but might be problematic.

In a situation like this, you can share a Python object<sup>1</sup> across multiple processes by serializing it using the [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module and storing the byte data in a database. A good place for the data would be something like Redis or Memcached but Django's ORM can be used as well:

```py
# yourapp/models.py
from django.db import models


class Session(models.Model):
    pickled = models.BinaryField()
```

```
# yourapp/views.py
import pickle

from django.http import HttpResponse
from requests import Session

from . import models


def use_session(request):
    # Load the pickled session from the database
    session_db_obj = models.Session.objects.first()

    if session_db_obj:
        # Un-pickle the session
        session = pickle.loads(session_db_obj.pickled)
    else:
        # Create a new session
        session = Session()
        session.post('https://httpbin.org/post')  # Setup Session by logging in

        # Create the database object, pickle the session and save it
        session_db_obj = models.Session()
        session_db_obj.pickled = pickle.dumps(session)
        session_db_obj.save()

    reply = session.get('https://example.com')  # Get resource from web service
    return HttpResponse(reply.content, status=reply.status_code)
```

---

<sup>1</sup>: Not any object can be pickled and unpickled reliably, be careful!

Comment: Thank you for your answer and pointing out the risk of multiple instances. In my application that is actually fine. I was also wondering whether Workers could be a solution, but I am not familiar enough with their principles.

Comment: Those API requests will be blocking the server thread, get enough of them on a day when your network feels a bit slow, and you'll be seeing 502 errors.
One way to fix this is to indeed move those calls to a worker. You'll need somehow to push the API response back to the user, which isn't trivial.
Another option for recent versions of Django is to use async views and async version of requests - grequests, but that also can get complicated, since now you need to learn about asyncio and Django doesn't support async fully yet

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best place to set this up is in `settings.py` since it's called before the application is initialized and you can easily import your code from there.

This being said, you may want to look into connection pooling or have a wrapper on top of your session which can recreate it in case of failure. Networks are not as reliable as they seem and if you plan to keep the session running for a long time it increases the chances that the session will be stopped at some point.

Comment: `requests.Session` is already doing connection pooling (by the means of `urllib3`) and will recreate a TCP connection just fine

Comment: Thank you for your answer and pointing out the need for some reconnecting function. I think that that can be achieved by reconnection after some time has passed. 

About placing the logic in settings.py. Isn’t that a bit of an odd choice? I’ve never seen logic in that file.